# Linux Mint - Calendar Locale (Change days name)

Tags: debian, linux-mint, locale, calendar

Using Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia on 64-bit, I cannot find out how to change the locale only for Calendar (changing Monday to Luni[Romanian] for example).

I want the rest of the things to stay on EN_US, but I need to change the calendar locale (days) to Romanian. I have tried editing the file in `/etc/default/locale`, but it still does not work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Run the calendar from terminal:

```
$ LC_ALL=ro_RO.UTF-8 <your calendar program>
```

But first generate the locales with `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I find out what my calendar program is? I'm using the built-in calendar from Linux Mint